# How to run jgrasp on ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, java

I have problems with jgrasp. I get the following error message when I run it.

> ----jGRASP exec: javac -g R.java  ----jGRASP wedge: could not execute
>   javac  ----   error number 2.  ----     ----   Target does not exist
>   or is not on PATH.  ----     ----     ----   PATH is
>   ":/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/bin:/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games".
>
> ----jGRASP: operation complete.

what should i do please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's trying to call `javac`, the java compiler.  This isn't installed as part of the java runtime environment (JRE).

On ubuntu I believe the package with the compiler has a `jdk` suffix, try:

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-6-jdk
```

You may want to change that '6' to a '7' to upgrade your java installation.

Comment: i tried to write your command but see :raghad@raghad-Latitude-E5430-non-vPro:~$ apt-get install openjdk-6-jdk
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?

Comment: if there is a different program that can program java and it works easily tell me plz  :)

Comment: Sorry, you need to run that with privileges, so `sudo ...` -- I've edited this in.  If you can't do that because this isn't your computer, ask a question, *"How can I install a java compiler to my home directory?"* and I'll answer that.